# Using water model in a computer program

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am writing a small simulator for situations where water is the medium of all reactions.

A quick googling confirmed that there are water models available in computer readable formats. Being a beginner in molecular chemistry, I was hoping someone can direct me to already mature libraries which I can use to read water models.

Following seems to be good candidates:

- http://msl-libraries.org/index.php/Main_Page
- http://ball-docs.bioinf.uni-sb.de

Comment: Can't get you correctly! Have you checked [Gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org/) and [Ambertools](http://ambermd.org/)?

Comment: Nope. Ambertools look very promising. Thank you. I was hoping for a small library which can read the water model and let me populate my own data-structures (CGAL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries which support Water model Simulation:

1. [Assisted Model Building with Energy Refinement(AMBER)](http://ambermd.org/)
2. [Chemistry at HARvard Macromolecular Mechanics(CHARMM)](http://www.charmm.org/)
3. [The Molecular Modelling Toolkit](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/MMTK/)

Cool Site for Water Model Generation:

[Water Models](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/models.html#back1)

[image]

Image Source: http://biomodel.uah.es/en/water/index.htm

Comment: I saw (what I think was) your recently deleted question posted automatically in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110113/whats-going-on-elsewhere). You may have seen [How can I calculate the charge distribution of a water molecule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/30933/16035) but this may be more helpful: [How to “get my feet wet” in Density Functional Theory by simulating a water molecule using Python](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1053/201)

Comment: @uhoh Thanks a lot! I was looking for this!